# How is digit grouping accomplished for a calculator. For instance digit grouping numbers the same way the Windows 7 calculator does

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm making a calculator application for windows phone 7 and I'm struggling with digit grouping. Here's the code:

myNumber = myNumber.Replace(",", string.Empty);

```
            int dot = myNumber.IndexOf("0.");

            strNumberWithoutDecimals = myNumber.Substring(0, (dot == -1 ? myNumber.Length : dot));
            strNumberDecimals = (dot == -1 ? "" : myNumber.Substring(dot));

            try
            {
                strNumberWithoutDecimals = Convert.ToDouble(strNumberWithoutDecimals).ToString("#,##0.000000000");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Ignore ... for now.
            }

            total = strNumberWithoutDecimals + strNumberDecimals; return total;
```

The problem is when the user enters say 0.323 and the digit grouping is on, the number can't be negative. It won't work. 0.323 cannot become -0.323 and I don't know why. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be familiar with C# string formatting support, both on input and output.

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Use `Double.TryParse()` with one of the overloads that includes style information.

e.g. `TryParse(string s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider, out double result)`

(There should be similar methods for Integer, Decimal, Float, etc depending on the precision you require).

This approach will also make your app more I18N friendly, as different cultures employ different conventions for digit grouping (e.g. many European cultures do 1.234.567,89 to represent 1,234,567.89)

`TryParse(string s, out double result)` should also work but with less control over the format of the input string.

These are functionally equivalent:

```
        double answer;
        var result = Double.TryParse("123,456.78", NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, out answer);
        Console.WriteLine("result: {0} answer {1}", result, answer);

        result = Double.TryParse("123,456.78", out answer);
        Console.WriteLine("result: {0} answer {1}", result, answer);
```

Note that `NumberStyles.Float` is a composite of other NumberStyles (e.g. `NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign`, `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint`, etc).

No need to manually strip out commas, etc!

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how you would use Double.TryParse() with some code?

Comment: Have updated answer with link to relevant MSDN page, there is a detailed example using culture-based parsing down the bottom I believe.

Comment: This is what I got, but it's not doing anything.             string val2 = inputPanelTextBox.Text;
            styles = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint & NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
            culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            if (Double.TryParse(val2, styles, culture, out answer))
                inputPanelTextBox.Text = "" + answer;

Comment: That's interesting... however, I notice that for my value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (en-AU) that the `Double.TryParse(string s, out double result)` overload successfully parses the string `123,456.78` to 123456.78. So that should work for you as well, its just less flexible.

Comment: In your comment, `styles = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint & NumberStyles.AllowThousands;` should be replaced with `styles = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;`... the bitwise flags should be OR'd together! Answer has been updated with a new example.

Comment: On the code that's in my question, digit grouping works fine. I'm going to make my appliation more I18N friendly as an update. But the thing is what my code is doing is it's adding the numbers that are just whole numbers with numbers that are just decimal numbers to produce numbers such as 32,232.2344. Well what if the user enters 0.323? The user then can't make that number negative. That's what I'm struggling with right now.

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at exactly, but both of the example usages of `Double.TryParse` in my answer support strings representing negative numbers.